# Not able to click the button after entering value in textarea Options

Tags: selenium, webdriver

code is used is:

```
WebElement desc=driver.findElementByXPath(".//*[@label='Description']");
  desc.sendKeys("testing");
 desc.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

  List<WebElement> button=driver.findElementsByXPath("(//div[@id='sv'])[1]");

  for (WebElement buttonname : button)
  {
          System.out.println("buttonname: "+buttonname.getAttribute("id"));
          String but = buttonname.getAttribute("id");
          driver.findElementById(but).click();
  }
```

Below is the html code of that textarea and button .

```
<td>
<textarea id="1992800000" label="Description" ft="12" mand="false"class="ic" maxlength="120" cols="13" rows="2"/>
</td>

......

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr style="height: 40px; ">
<td class="pdl">
<div class="tbut" onclick="ir('Tas','tas','')" id="sv">Save</div>
</td>
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: no error but save button is not clicked!

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath can only select one element, so there is no need to create a list and iterate through it.
Try something more like:

```
WebElement desc=driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@label='Description']"); 
desc.sendKeys("testing");  
WebElement button=driver.findElementsByXPath("(//div[@id='sv'])[1]");
button.click();
```

Comment: What doesn't work, entering text in the field or clicking the save button?

Comment: clicking save button.if i remove the code related to description field it will work (1st 2 lines above).

Comment: If the description field runs some javascript when it's modified, you may need to wait for the script to finish before continuing the test, try throwing in a wait or clicking the button a couple of times.